# Keras' model.predict() produces very different accuracy when calling on multiple batches at once VS calling on individual batches one by one

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

This is the model I've used:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=200, input_shape=(15, 17), return_sequences=True)
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(units=unit_per_layer))     
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(units=unit_per_layer, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(drop_out))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=opti_func, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Now, after `model.fit()`, when I call `model.predict(X_dataset_multiple_batch)` I get some good predictions. However, if I devide `X_dataset_multiple_batch` into a series of individual batches (let's call each of them `X_dataset_single_batch`) and call `model.predict(X_dataset_single_batch)` on them one by one (i.e. call `model.predict(X_dataset_single_batch)` multiple times), the predictions become much worse than the former one.

**Additional Note**
Honestly I only need the last prediction, but because of Keras internal design stuff, I cannot have only one single prediction. It has to be in batches. So I have to do my predictions on batches and then extract the last prediction. This is fine, but the question now becomes what is the optimum number of batches that I have to give `model.predict()`?

#### A wild guess

Isn't this related to the way LSTM resets its state after each batch?

#### Update 1

This is how I pick individual batches from my test.csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Data/Test_file.csv")

X_ = df.loc[:, 'b':'dm'].to_numpy()
Y_ = df.loc[:, 'dn'].to_numpy()

predictions = []

for i in range (0, 2 + X_.shape[0] - (n_batch + time_step)):
    X = X_[i:i+n_batch+time_step]
    Y = Y_[i:i+n_batch+time_step]

    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    X_one_batch_of_data = np.zeros((n_batch, time_step, X.shape[1]))
    
    for j in range(0, X_one_batch_of_data.shape[0]):
        X_one_batch_of_data[j] = X[j:j+time_step, :]

    predictions.append(model.predict(X_one_batch_of_data, batch_size=n_batch)[-1, 0])
```

Comment: what do you mean by dividing dataset into a series of individual batches ? `model.fit()` always divide your data to batches (batch_size of 32 on default). Did you add an additional dimension ? Would be great if you added this code

Comment: You have mentioned "after `model.fit()` when I call `model.fit(...)`", do you mean you call the `fit` method two times? Or is this a typo and in all the places (except the first one) you are actually referring to the `predict` method?

Comment: @today You're right; I edited my question. Thanks mate. How come did I make such a silly mistake?!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the `accuracy` you are mentioning, do you have any numbers? Are you running prediction on a whole dataset? When you say  `the predictions become much worse than the former one.`, how do you compare the former and the latter?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani You should post the code where you split the dataset and call predict because the problem is probably there.

Comment: Don't change the preprocessing steps in prediction phase; rather, use the same preprocessing steps and stats, computed over training data, on the test data (i.e. look at the lines where you scale the data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically preprocessing (scaling) your data differently at training and test time.

The lesson here is that if your preprocessing pipeline is fit on data (like your `MinMaxScaler` is*), it should be fit on training data and saved in order to be re-used at test time. In this way, you are sure that test data receives the same treatment of training data (that's what your model know how to process).

(*) `MinMaxScaler` finds the minimum and maximum value of each features in the dataset. Of course, training and test datasets may have different min and max values for some or all the features.

Comment: Honestly I didn't quite catch your point. MinMaxScaler transforms a bunch of numbers so that they stay between 0 and 1. How does it matter if I do it now or a later time? Or how does it matter if I do it on train data and test data separately?

Comment: To scale data, MinMaxScaler needs to find the min and max of each feature. See the documentation for the formula it applies. The point is that training and test data are not guaranteed to have the same min and max for each feature. In your case, I'm pretty sure they haven't. So you are applying a different scaling at training and test time.